# My computer screen kept showing horizontal lines and now its only black screen

Tags: windows

Hey please help me out..
my laptop started blinking with horizontal lines displaying on the screen. it will start booting normally but after 18 or 20 seconds the screen starts shaking again and lots of horizontal lines gets on the screen. it comes and sometimes stops by itself and comes again and again jus like that.
 sometimes why its on it will just start showing lines of the screen all over...

but after 2 days, now it is worse, when I press the power bottom it comes on but only blank black screen is displayed..
the thinkpad lenovo logo dont show anymore. only black screen
please find a way to help me out.

Comment: It might be useful to mention what your laptop *model* is. It does sound a lot like some component such as the GPU is failing tho

Comment: In addition to Aibobot's advice, you might try attaching an external monitor. If you are lucky (?), then the GPU is OK and the screen is dead. I believe screens are a bit easier to replace that GPUs because GPUs are usually soldered on the mainboard. If the GPU is intact, you can continue to use it with the external monitor.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop and get it properly diagnosed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the Laptop is under Warranty/extended warranty (if so take it to warranty)
2. Take out the ODD/HDD( lessen power draw )
3. If you have 2 RAM modules, take out 1, try to boot
4. If nothing changed swap the models to make sure is not a MEM problem
5. If steps 3 and 4 have no result, please find a VGA/HDMI Monitor and Cables
6. Connect your Laptop through VGA or HDMI to a External display
7. Boot the laptop, and FIND ON YOUR KEYBOARD <kbd>FN</kbd>(button) + <kbd>F5</kbd> could be <kbd>F4</kbd> just check(or any other button which forces dual screen/projector scanning).
8. If the external display does not start, don't worry wait for 5-10 minutes after starting laptop, and press <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (windows button on keyboard) (once)
   Then press Right arrow twice and hit enter (Extended mode).
9. If the external monitor LIT up, SHUTDOWN PC fast, and try te re-apply ThermalPlaster (thermalpaste) to your GPU/CPU (if integrated) cooling, and clean out your FAN or change the FAN if RPM's are too low.
   9.1 And try to run, it could be because no Coolant is left and the GPU is overheating
10. If nothing happened means your GPU is dead congrats, only option is to RE-HEAT it and hope that it works, then sell the laptop because it will work for MAX for 3 months till it will die again.

EDIT:2018

If it is WINDOWS 10 it may be that Faulty drivers are initialized.
Try to check if u can see BOOT MENU (F9 or F11 or F12) based on the laptop, on start. and check if u can set BOPOT OPTION to a LINUX USB LIVE CD and try to boot from it, if this shows the full GUI with no artifacts means that the WIN10 drivers are faulty, which is a normal occurance, a clean install and inject correct drivers in drivers store would fix that :)

Comment: i powered it on and it displayed with the horizontal Lines scratching and flickering again, but after the windows10 logo left it turn blank again. 
so I tried step 2, 3and4 but its not working...
I did connect it to a monitor using the VGA cable but its still blank screen

Comment: Well as i said, it seems your GPU (probably integrated) is fried.
Why it shows WIN logo and after disappears = after win logo advanced GPU drivers get loaded and then GPU fails.

A way arround it would be to boot into a LIVE USB to see if VGA ctually fails.

If so like i said, you need to clean it up, and hope after cleaning up you know allowing it to breathe more ( no dust inside, new thermalpaste ), should allow you to boot.

But by the things youve said im guessing 95% it is dead, no point in fixing, its cheaper to get for 100pounds a new/refurbished T400 or x230 :D

Comment: can it be replaced fro another computer??

Comment: Here's a guide on getting a bootable copy of Ubuntu onto a USB drive, credits to @Keltari